# Getting individual XML childnodes with c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am currently trying to get some XML data and rework it into another format for a project I am working on. Now I am able to get the childnodes of what I am doing, but I can't seem to get it to split the child nodes up. This is the XML data I am getting.

```
<Race xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Checkpoints>
    <Vector3>
       <X>237.477936</X>
       <Y>936.0487</Y>
       <Z>209.590744</Z>
    </Vector3>
    <Vector3>
       <X>163.06778</X>
       <Y>922.664856</Y>
       <Z>208.251434</Z>
    </Vector3>
    <Vector3>
       <X>74.3054</X>
       <Y>1022.99408</Y>
       <Z>215.625259</Z>
    </Vector3>
    <Vector3>
       <X>20.2580948</X>
       <Y>1040.94922</Y>
       <Z>217.798935</Z>
    </Vector3>
</Checkpoints>
</Race>
```

No I am trying to grab the X, Y and Z of each vector and construct them into a table like the following,

```
{X, Y, Z, 8.0}
```

I am currently doing this

```
            XmlNodeList checkNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Race/Checkpoints");

                foreach (XmlNode aNode in checkNodes)
                {
                    for (var w = 0; w < aNode.ChildNodes.Count; w++)
                    {
                        string checkpoint = "";

                        string xPos = aNode.ChildNodes[w].InnerText.ToString();
                        string yPos = aNode.ChildNodes[w].InnerText.ToString();
                        string zPos = aNode.ChildNodes[w].InnerText.ToString();

                        checkpoint = "{" + xPos + ", " + yPos + ", " + zPos + ", 8.0},";
                        xnTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + checkpoint);
                    }
                }
```

But I am not able to break down individual child components, it will only output all of them like so

```
{237.477936936.0487209.590744, 237.477936936.0487209.590744, 237.477936936.0487209.590744, 8.0},
{163.06778922.664856208.251434, 163.06778922.664856208.251434, 163.06778922.664856208.251434, 8.0},
{74.30541022.99408215.625259, 74.30541022.99408215.625259, 74.30541022.99408215.625259, 8.0},
```

and yeah I know that yPos and zPos are outputting the same as zPos thats because I cant work out how to split the childnodes. Any help would be great, Thankyou.

**Edit:**

I have created the answer below into a class and it works, but now I have a further nested element I need to get but when I try to add it, it only returns one row and not the heading.

This is the class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("Race")]
public class Race
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Checkpoints")]
    public Checkpoints Checkpoints { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SpawnPoints")]
    public SpawnPoints SpawnPoints { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Vector3")]
public class Checkpoints
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Vector3")]
    public List<Vector3> Vectors { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Vector3")]
public class Vector3
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "X")]
    public double X { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Y")]
    public double Y { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Z")]
    public double Z { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("SpawnPoints")]
public class SpawnPoints
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SpawnPoint")]
    public SpawnPoint SpawnPoint { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Position")]
public class SpawnPoint
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Position")]
    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Position")]
public class Position
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "X")]
    public double X { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Y")]
    public double Y { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Z")]
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the XML data I am trying to retrieve. I need to get the X, Y, Z and the heading.

```
<Race>
<SpawnPoints>
<SpawnPoint>
  <Position>
    <X>272.181335</X>
    <Y>953.0988</Y>
    <Z>211.16713</Z>
  </Position>
  <Heading>124.781677</Heading>
</SpawnPoint>
<SpawnPoint>
  <Position>
    <X>271.212</X>
    <Y>957.0102</Y>
    <Z>211.007156</Z>
  </Position>
  <Heading>121.86322</Heading>
</SpawnPoint>
<SpawnPoint>
  <Position>
    <X>270.4751</X>
    <Y>961.3033</Y>
    <Z>210.899719</Z>
  </Position>
  <Heading>118.801186</Heading>
</SpawnPoint>
<SpawnPoint>
  <Position>
    <X>270.059875</X>
    <Y>965.9859</Y>
    <Z>210.793045</Z>
  </Position>
  <Heading>106.5283</Heading>
</SpawnPoint>
<SpawnPoint>
  <Position>
    <X>269.029266</X>
    <Y>970.9914</Y>
    <Z>210.521118</Z>
  </Position>
  <Heading>107.501411</Heading>
</SpawnPoint>
<SpawnPoint>
</Race>
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger to see where it's not doing what you think it's doing? In every run through your for loop, `xPos`, `yPos` and `zPos` are all getting assigned the same value because they're all using the same value of `w` to point to the same thing.

Comment: I am aware of that. I am asking how to get each individual or a specific childnode rather then all of the childnodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably going to want to use the [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.1) class
from the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace. This is a tool specifically designed for pulling data out of XML-derived data formats. This is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

It works in two primary steps:

1. First, you create a set of classes that represent the data structure.
2. You create an `XmlSerializer` and call [XmlSerializer.Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.7.1) with your data.

In your scenario, you would create three classes. `Race`, `Checkpoints`, and `Vector3`:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// Represents the <Race> XML tag.
[XmlRoot("Race")]
class Race
{
    // Because the <Checkpoints> tag is contained by the <Race> tag,
    // the class representation of the <Checkpoints> tag should be contained
    // by the class representation of the <Race> tag.
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Checkpoints")]
    public Checkpoints Checkpoints { get; set; }
}

// Represents a <Checkpoints> XML tag.
[XmlRoot("Vector3")]
class Checkpoints 
{
    // Same as above but for <Vector3> tags.
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Vector3")]
    public List<Vector3> Vectors { get; set; }
}

// Represents a <Vector3> XML tag.
[XmlRoot("Vector3")]
class Vector3 
{
    // The <X> element in the <Vector3> tag
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "X")]
    public double X { get; set; }

    // Same
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Y")]
    public double Y { get; set; }

    // Same
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Z")]
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to create a `XmlSerializer` and use it to deserialize your XML data into a C# `Race` object.

```
// Wherever you get your XML from.
// You can also use a TextReader object,
// which means either a StreamReader or StringReader
// so you can use strings as well.
using(Stream xmlFile = File.OpenRead(""))
{
    // Create a new XmlSerializer that deserializes
    // instances of the Race class from XML.
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Race));

    Race race = (Race)serializer.Deserialize(xmlFile);

    // Tada!
    // You now have all of your data in
    // a normal C# object.

    foreach(Vector3 vector in race.Checkpoints.Vectors) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X: {0} Y: {1} Z: {2}", vector.X, vector.Y, vector.Z);
    }
}
```

See also:

- [XML Serialization & Deserialization Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)
- [XmlSerializer API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.1)

**Edit:**

The key is that `SpawnPoints` does not just contain a *single* `SpawnPoint`, but many. As such, you need to change `public SpawnPoint SpawnPoint { get; set; }` into `public List<SpawnPoint> Points { get; set; }`. The reverse is true for the `Positions` element in the `SpawnPoint` class.

Comment: How I didn't. That works perfectly, I will adapt this for my future nodes I need to get. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Can you please check my original question, I added an edit with another issue I came across. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Thanks again got everything sorted, Added the extra loop and added a variable to catch the heading as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty concisely with LINQ:

```
XmlNodeList vecNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Race/Checkpoints/Vector3");
var checkpoints =
  from node in vecNodes.Cast<XmlNode>()
  let dict = node.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().ToDictionary(n => n.Name, n => n.InnerText)
  select "{" + dict["X"] + ", " + dict["Y"] + ", " + dict["Z"] + ", 8.0},";

foreach (var checkpoint in checkpoints)
  Console.WriteLine(checkpoint);

{237.477936, 936.0487, 209.590744, 8.0},
{163.06778, 922.664856, 208.251434, 8.0},
{74.3054, 1022.99408, 215.625259, 8.0},
{20.2580948, 1040.94922, 217.798935, 8.0},
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to using xml linq and have only one class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            SpawnPoint.points = doc.Descendants("SpawnPoint").Select(x => new SpawnPoint() {
                x = x.Descendants("X").Select(y => (double)y).FirstOrDefault(),
                y = x.Descendants("Y").Select(y => (double)y).FirstOrDefault(),
                z = x.Descendants("Z").Select(y => (double)y).FirstOrDefault(),
                heading = (double)x.Element("Heading")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class SpawnPoint
    {
        public static List<SpawnPoint> points = new List<SpawnPoint>();

        public double x { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
        public double z { get; set; }
        public double heading { get; set; }

    }
}
```